# How to rename catalog of ADW Launcher EX?

Tags: launcher, paid-apps, adw.launcher, adw-launcher-ex

In *Setup Catalog* option, I can only choose apps, but can't rename the catalog. Is there any way to rename a catalog?

Comment: My ADW Launcher has just been updated to 1.3.3.8 which features App Group renaming...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I've found to do this is to edit the XML file that stores the name directly. It should be at `/data/data/org.adwfreak.launcher/shared_prefs/APP_CATALOG_Index.xml`:

```
# cd /data/data/org.adwfreak.launcher/shared_prefs
cd /data/data/org.adwfreak.launcher/shared_prefs
# ls
ls
APP_CATALOG_1.xml       APP_CATALOG_Index.xml   adw_ex_preferences.xml
# more APP_CATALOG_Index.xml
more APP_CATALOG_Index.xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
<string name="GrpName1">First Group</string>
</map>
```

Edit the value within the `GrpName#` tag that corresponds to the group you want to rename and then restart ADW Launcher. AFAIK there's no way to do it in the ADW UI itself (aside from deleting and recreating it, but that's inconvenient, too).